# How to make a Facebook FQL query to select all friends

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-fql

I'm new with PHP SDK Facebook, so sorry if that quesiton is stupid.

So, i have this code

```
SELECT name FROM user
    WHERE current_location.country = 'Italy' AND
    uid IN (
        SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()
    )
```

That responses me:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Matilde xxxx"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Samson xxxxxxxx"
    },  
    {
      "name": "Emanuela xxxxxxx"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm using this site to analyze how to manage the json :http://chris.photobooks.com/json/default.htm

i saw that if i want to have a request of the name of a friend i have to do that:
root.data[5].name

so that is my php code :

```
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();


$all_friends = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => 'SELECT name FROM user
        WHERE current_location.country = "Italy" AND
        uid IN (
            SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = 1068943079
        ) '));
        $val = 1;
        echo $all_friends['data'][$val]['name'];
```

(is a test, i want to see the friend at key=1) but there is only white page... show nothing.. and if i do echo $all_friends i see Array.

Sorry if this is a stupid question, i know that i can use another method to do that..but i want to know how to do it with this way!
Thank you, and sorry for my language.

That is all my code :
[CLICK HERE TO SEE MY CODE](http://www.baratellamarco.it/php/examples/code.txt)

Comment: When you say that `$all_friends` _shows Array_. Do you mean that it displays the entire array or does it only display the word `Array`?

Comment: there is only Array( )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. You should `print_r($all_friends)` to check the structure of the array

Try

```
echo $all_friends[$val]['name'];
```

#### 2. The FQL query should only occur when `$user != 0`.

Place it under the `if` statement

#### 3. You didn't ask for the `read_friendlists` permission

```
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'read_friendlists'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

Doc:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friendlist/

Comment: What is the value of `$user_id`?

Comment: Is the login function

Comment: Yes, so what's the value of the `$user_id` var? It should not be `0`.

Comment: Ok, understood the question, wowowowo Is 0! Maybe found the problem! Ty ill try to solve my problem

Comment: Now user id is my id, but with  echo $all_friends['data'][$val]['name']; or echo $all_friends[$val]['name']; do nothing, white page.

With print_r($all_friends) , i take that: Array ( )

Comment: I guess you are missing too much things (think to permissions). I need to see all your code related to the Facebook API. It can't be only what you've shown to us. [Here is an example](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) which you can start from.

Comment: Post updated. Try to solve the problems, be smart and do the right verifications.